# Running Imagick convert from C# via new Process

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing

I'm trying to resize a 800x600 picture into a 8000x6000. I am using `imagick` for this, but I cannot run it from code.

This is my code :

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int randomNumber = rnd.Next(111111111, 999999999);
string ip = "1.2.3.4";

CaptureScreenPng(8, 30, 800, 600, "screenshots\\" + ip + "-" + randomNumber.ToString() + ".rdpscreenshot.png");
// search_in_hocr_for_app_on_desktop("LRSRK");

// CaptureScreen(8, 30, 800, 600, "screenshots\\" + ip + "-" + randomNumber.ToString() + ".rdpscreenshot.bmp");

// resize
System.Diagnostics.Process resize = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
resize.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-7.0.1-Q16\\convert";
resize.StartInfo.Arguments = "screenshots\\" + ip + "-" + randomNumber.ToString() + ".rdpscreenshot.png -resize 200% screenshots\\" + ip + "-" + randomNumber.ToString() + ".rdpscreenshot.big.png"; //argument
resize.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
resize.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
resize.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
resize.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; //not diplay a windows
resize.Start();
string output = resize.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); //The output result
resize.WaitForExit();

Console.WriteLine(output); // --> nothing
Console.WriteLine("C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-7.0.1-Q16\\convert screenshots\\" + ip + "-" + randomNumber.ToString() + ".rdpscreenshot.png -resize 200% screenshots\\" + ip + "-" + randomNumber.ToString() + ".rdpscreenshot.big.png");
// --> output ->>  "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.0.1-Q16\convert" screenshots\1.2.3.4-957447099.rdpscreenshot.png -resize 1000% screenshots\1.2.3.4-957447099.rdpscreenshot.big.png
// witch works
```

It is only creating the screenshot, but it doesn't resize it. If I run the command from `CMD` in the `Debug` folder, it is working.

Where am I wrong? What error message may I get? I don't see anything.

Thanks.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but take a look at Magick.NET (http://magick.codeplex.com/). It's an API for ImageMagick and very easy to use.

Comment: Side note: 8000x6000 is a lot... not every tool/format would work correctly with that - before complaining about C# not working make sure you can do it directly with the tool from command line.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov and what the solution might be? Clearly we have an escaping thing or something like this, or enviroment variables ...

Comment: I'd start with checking what `resize.StartInfo.Arguments` ends up being set to and gaining understanding of "current working folder" and how relative path are converted into absolute.